# Limiting per user backend resource usage with nginx proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, proxy, unicorn

I am using nginx to proxy to a unicorn upstream running a Ruby on Rails application. I want to be able to limit the total amount of the backend resources a singe user (IP address) can consume. By backend resources, I mean the number of active requests a user can have running on the upstream unicorn processes at once.

So for example, if an IP address already has 2 writing connections to a particular upstream, I want any further requests to be queued by nginx, until one of the previously open connections is complete. Note that I don't want requests to be dropped - they should just wait until the number of writing connections drops below 2 for the user.

This way, I can ensure that even if one user attempts many requests for a very time consuming action, they don't consume all of the available upstream unicorn workers, and some unicorn workers are still available to service other users.

It seems like ngx_http_limit_conn_module might be able to do this, but the documentation is not clear enough for me to be sure.

Another way to think about the problem is that I want to protect against DoS (but not DDoS, i.e. I only care about DoS from one IP at a time), by making the server appear to any one IP address as if it has the ability to process N simultaneous requests. But in reality the server can process 10*N requests, but I am limiting the simultaneous requests from any one IP to 1/10th of the server's real capacity. Just like a normal server behaves, when the number of simultaneous workers is exceeded requests are queued until previous requests have completed.

Comment: Sorry, the ngx_http_limit_conn module will not queue connections - it will immediately reject any excess connection attempts with the error code set by the limit_conn_status line. (usually 503).

Comment: I haven't been able to find a good solution to this problem, so we are implementing an Nginx module to do what we need.

Answer (score 2):

You can user limit_req module
http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html

It doesn't limit number of connections, but it limits requests per second. Just use large burst to delay request and not to drop them.

Here's example.

```
http {
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=2r/s;
    ...
    server {
        ...
        location / {
            limit_req zone=one burst=50;
        }
```

You know that average request processing time is say 1 second, so setting limit to 2r/s allows only two workers being busy with this particular ip address (approximately, of course). If request takes 0.5 sec to complete, you can set 4r/s.

Comment: This doesn't help with what I want to do. The problem is that some requests might take a short time to process and some might take a long time. It would be OK to make a lot of short requests in the same amount of time that only a smaller amount of long requests would be acceptable. So a rate is not a useful way of limiting the resources for a user.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the time consuming url, then you can make use of the limit_req module to implement 2r/s for the long requests, and no limit for short requests.

```
http {
    ...
    #
    # Limit request processing rate or connection
    # If IP address is 127.0.0.1, the limit_conn_zone will not count it.
    #
    geo $custom_remote_addr $custom_limit_ip {
        default     $binary_remote_addr;
        127.0.0.1   "";
    }
    limit_req_zone $custom_limit_ip zone=perip:10m rate=2r/s;
    ...
    server {
        ...
        # By default, do not enforce the maximum allowed number of connections for the remote IP
        set $custom_remote_addr 127.0.0.1;

        # If the URI matches a super time consuming requests, limit to 2r/s.
        if ($uri ~* "^/super-long-requests") {
            set $custom_remote_addr $remote_addr;
        }
        limit_req zone=perip burst=50;
        ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: The problem is not one specifically of slow requests. A user might make many short requests and still be able to saturate the server's resources. More importantly, the reason I want this protection is that I don't know ahead of time what requests might be slow or fast. The idea is to ensure that regardless of how the server behaves, one user can't consume all the resources.

Comment: If you do not even know [1] which are the slow and fast requests, then you probably have to go with a generic approach - set a rate of requests coming from a IP address (as provided by the other user) or get a firewall.

#1 - Don't you have a log?